Why does the Bulma CSS framwork change the z-index on hover?
I am looking into rendering performance issues of my website and I have found that I get a lot of repaints while just moving the mouse pointer around.
Example: the HTML-Box below the input field and button get a repaint each time I move the mouse pointer (hovering only) between the input and the button in this page (from the official Bulma docs)

I am using the Bulma CSS framework with an "add-on"-arrangement on some elements. A deeper analysis has show that such buttons and inputs have their z-index changed on hover. The relevant scss code in Bulma is this:
From tools.scss:
  .#{iv.$class-prefix}button,
  .#{iv.$class-prefix}input,
  .#{iv.$class-prefix}select select {
    &:not([disabled]) {
      &:hover,
      &.#{iv.$class-prefix}is-hovered {
        z-index: 2;
      }

      &:focus,
      &.#{iv.$class-prefix}is-focused,
      &:active,
      &.#{iv.$class-prefix}is-active {
        z-index: 3;

        &:hover {
          z-index: 4;
        }
      }
    }
  }

What is the logic behind such a z-index change on hover?
It's causing a ton of repaints on my quite complex website. Do other CSS frameworks have a similar function? I am tempted to remove/neuter these z-index changes.

Without the z-index hack, part of the prefix button border (in focus) will be covered by the input field, which look like this:


Ah, I see. Well I could live with that, because it's really hurting for me. Maybe I will decide to remove the "shiny" border altogether. With Bulma, at least with my theme, the button color sligtly changes anyway on hover, indicating the hovered state good enoufh for me.
